# I have a wordpress Multisite where I want to load content from one site on a different domain

Tags: .htaccess, multisite

We have a multisite wodpress installation we did for the domains clubsmart.dk /.se /.no /.fi where we would like to add a few more domains, though not new sites.

The new domains should point to the existing ones, so that when entering one of the new domains which for example is se.clubsmart.one the user should see the same content as on clubsmart.se

I was thinking I could use domain aliases, but that is not a feature at our host, so it proberbly needs to be set up in the wordpress multisite admin or in the htaccessfile if possible?

we added the domains as addon domains on the account, so currently they are all redirecting to the accounts rootdomain which is: clubsmart.dk

so the result should be that:
The content of clubsmart.dk should be accessable from both dk.clubsmart.one and clubsmart.dk

Can any of you help with that?

Comment: Other than setting up a proxy solution that includes modifying the content, I don’t know if this is feasible at all. WordPress still has the habit of using _absolute_ URLs all over the place, so even if you could “trick” it into showing the content of `clubsmart.dk` under `dk.clubsmart.one` initially, clicking on the first link would probably lead back directly to `clubsmart.dk` again.

Comment: So this is not the solution I guess. What would be the solution then?